# Django expire cache every N'th HTTP request

Tags: django, caching

I have a Django view which needs can be cached, however it needs to be recycled every 100th time when the view is called by the HTTP request.

I cannot use the interval based caching here since the number will keep changing upon traffic.

How would I implement this? Are there other nice methods around except maintaining a counter (in db) ?

Comment: Seems like you may want to write a custom [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas / feedback:

You're going to have to centralize something if you need it to be exact - the Redis idea in this linked solution looks OK if you can't put it in the main DB. If Redis is in your stack, I'd use that. If the 100 requests can be per user and you're using sessions, you could attach a counter to the session.

[implementing a counter that counts requests with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880133/implementing-a-counter-that-counts-requests-with-django)

To not centralize the counter outside of the webserver would mean your app needs to be and stay single-threaded to keep counts in memory. It would also reset if the server was restarted. Not a great idea IMO...

If you really can't make it work with anything else, you could hack something like a request counter on your load balancer (...if the load balancer is a single machine you control, and you're comfortable doing that) and pass it as a header for Django to read.